# Is it possible to change the magnifier icon on IBM Carbon Search component for React?

Tags: reactjs, ibm-cloud

Despite having searched all the documentation, and even writing to the design team on Twitter, I still can't find an answer to this question.

I would like to change the magnifier icon on the React Search component of the IBM Carbon component library.

Does anyone know if it is possible, and how to do it?